# If $\mu_r(m)=rm$ then ker $(\mu_r)$ and coker $(\mu_r)$ are modules over $R/I$

Tags: commutative-algebra, modules

Let R be a commutative ring with unity and M be an R-module.
Let $\mu_r:M\rightarrow M$ be the map $\mu_r(m)=rm$. Then  prove that ker $(\mu_r)$ and coker $(\mu_r)$ are both modules over $R/I$ where $I=\langle r\rangle$.

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: And what are $R, M$ and $x$ (assuming $r\in R$ and $m\in M$ already)...

Comment: But most importantly, what is $x$?

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** All you have to do is show that if $a \in I$ then $a\cdot m = 0$ for all $m \in \ker \mu_r$ and for all $m \in \mathrm{coker} \ \mu_r$.  To do this note first show that it's true when $a = r$ and then use the fact that $a \in I$ implies $a = br$ for some $b \in R$.